# Sampling to maximize model accuracy

Tags: sampling, decision-theory

Suppose you have a relatively small random sample and have a corresponding model 
$\ Y$ ~ $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p_i) $

$\ \operatorname{logit}( \hat{p_i} )=\hat{\beta}*X$ and now want to draw a sample of a fixed size in order to maximize the accuracy over the entire universe of the $\hat{p_i}$ generated after I refit the model with the new data.

The idea being that there might be subgroups that are a large percent of the population but have extremely predictable opinion, meaning that you don't need to sample very many of them to get an accurate model.

This, or some variant, has to be a pretty well known problem. Is there any literature I can read about it?

Comment: It's not *quite* what you're asking, but - mostly in the case of regression - [optimal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_design) addresses the issue of choosing the values of the IVs to optimize some outcome.